# "The name "Asset Database" does not exist in the current context" error while building unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My teacher gave me a challenge in unity (c#) where I have to load prefabs into an array (as a `GameObject[]` function). The code I have works in the editor, but when I build the game, it gives me the error `The name "Asset Database" does not exist in the curernt context`. The code I have currently is:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System;

public class FindCards : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string directoryName;
    public List<GameObject> foundGameObjects;

    public GameObject[] ListOfCards()
    {
        // get the directory and the files in them
        DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Application.dataPath + directoryName);

        FileInfo[] fileInfo = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.prefab");

        // loop through the files
        foreach(FileInfo file in fileInfo)
        {
            // get the path to the directory again (with proper formatting)
            string fullPath = file.FullName.Replace(@"\","/");
            string assetPath = "Assets" + fullPath.Replace(Application.dataPath, "");
    
    
            GameObject _asset;
            // load the asset from the direcotry
            _asset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath(assetPath, typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;            

            // add it to the list
            foundGameObjects.Add(_asset);
            Debug.Log(_asset.name);
        }


        // return the list as an array
        return(foundGameObjects.ToArray());
    }

    public void SetCardProperties(string cardName, Card card)
    {
        // get the first string, and the int
        // from the card's name
        string[] sub = cardName.Split('_');

        // (if the name was Diamond_07,     // string name
        // there would be an int = 07 and   // name[0]
        // a string = Diamond)              // name[1]
        card.suit = sub[0];
        Int32.TryParse(sub[1], out card.number);
    }
}
```

The code that is calling this function looks like this (note that this is in a different script):

```
private void Start()
{
    canScore = true;
    gameIsGoing = true;

    // set up cards
    cards = findCards.ListOfCards();

    for (int i = 0; i < cards.Length; i++)
    {
        Card card = cards[i].GetComponent<Card>();

        findCards.SetCardProperties(cards[i].name, card);
    }

    // set up deck
    ResetDeck();
}
```

The directory here:
[Prefabs in the directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvaU1.png)

Errors here:
[Errors unity gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18GPD.png)

I have been pulling my hair out, because there was nothing online I could find that would help me. My teacher gave this to me as challenge because he also did not know how to do it which is why I'm asking this question...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `AssetDatabase` belongs to the `UnityEditor` namespace and can not be used in a built application .. you will have to find another way. Depends on your task but usually you simply reference prefabs via the Inspector from within Unity in serialized fields -> no need to do this on runtime actually. Otherwise you could use `Resources.Load` or `AssetBundle`s

Comment: Yep, that worked... thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

AssetsDatabase it seems that works only in Editor. Check this thread for more info:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1068055/assetdatabase.html

Edit:

`Resources.Load()´ search in the path: "Assets/Resources".

Look what [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) says:

> If an asset can be found at path, it is returned with type `T`, otherwise returns null. If the file at path is of a type that cannot be converted to `T`, also returns null. The path is relative to any folder named Resources inside the Assets folder of your project. More than one Resources folder can be used. For example, a project may have Resources folders called Assets/Resources and @@AssetsAssetsResources@@. The path does not need to include Assets and Resources in the string, for example loading a GameObject at @@AssetspathShotgun.prefab@@ would only require Shotgun as the path. Also, if @@AssetspathMissiles/PlasmaGun.prefab exists it can be loaded using GunspathPlasmaGun@@ as the path string. If you have multiple Resources folders you cannot duplicate the use of an asset name.

Comment: So how do you add this in code? I have: GameObject _asset = Resources.Load<GameObject>(file.Name); but it gives me a null reference error (object reference)?

Comment: First try to check if the file exist. `System.IO.File.Exists(Application.dataPath + "Resources/file01.obj") ` Then get the asset.

Comment: Ok, I have done that, there is a file, for each of the prefabs, there is a log saying true, but for some reason, when i use the "GameObject i = Resources.Load<GameObject>(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/ " + file.Name;, it gives me an error saying that the gameobject was i is null?

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct path? Where do you have those, prefabs sotred in? As I see in the image you presented, the path would be: Assets/Cards/[prefab-name]

Comment: Oh no, I figured it out! I was supposed to use "Resources.LoadAll" with the path file. Sorry, but I was reading through the documentation until I stumbled across it. Thanks for the help anyway! (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html)  Edit: i didn't realize you had edited your comment!